# Cannot retrieve firebase json from database using reactFire

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, reactfire

I am tring to connect to my firebase using reactFire

This is my root of json "glossary"

```
var firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('/glossary');
console.log(firebaseRef)
```

But when in console if get the following

```
U {k: Bh, path: K, n: ce, bc: false}
bc
:
false
k
:
Bh
n
:
ce
path
:
K
__proto__
:
Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reference to a database location does not yet have the actual data at that location. To get the data, you will need to listen for it. For example:

```
firebaseRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
})
```

Note that this is all covered in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start). I highly recommend you spend some time there.